# Field_for in nested attributes is giving problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to both programming and Ruby on Rails. I'm just trying with a sample 2 level deep nesting. When I followed Ryan's Scraps (http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) for 1 level deep nesting everything well and good but when I extended for 2 level deep with following requirement:
    Instead of creating parent, children and grandchildren at a time  I want to create parent first then child and grandchild together.My code is

My model:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :children
has_many :grand_children
accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :grand_children, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :parent
has_many :grand_children
accepts_nested_attributes_for :grand_children
end

class GrandChild < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :parent
belongs_to :child
end
```

My children controller -new method:

```
    def new
@parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
child = Child.new
child.grand_children.build
respond_to do |format|
format.html # new.html.erb
format.xml  { render :xml => @child }
end
end
```

My children _form template is

```
<%= form_for([@parent, @parent.children.build]) do |form|  %>  
<div>
<%= form.label :name %><br />
<%= form.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :sex %><br />
<%= form.text_field :sex %>
</div>
<div>
<%= form.fields_for :grand_children do |grand_child_form| %>
<%= render :partial => "grand_children/form", :locals => { :form => grand_child_form}     %>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Here I'm not getting any error as such but when I select new child the grand_child is not appearing,

```
 <%= form.fields_for :grand_children do |grand_child_form| %>
  <%= render :partial => "grand_children/form", :locals => { :form => grand_child_form} %>
<% end %>
```

is not getting reflected at all .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey folks I got d solution by trial and error,

form template for children is

```
<div>
<%= form.fields_for :grandchildren, @grand_child do |grand_child_form| %>
<%= render :partial => "grandchildren/form", :locals => { :form => grand_child_form} %>
<% end %>
</div>
```